# Python error while appending in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, range

```
list=[range(130,135),range(135,140),range(140,145),range(145,150),range(150,155),range(155,160),range(160,165)]

x1= [x1 for x1.append(int(np.median(i))) in list]
```

When I run these to lines of code, I get an error which says can't assign to function call. Can someone help please

Comment: what do you *expect* `for x1.append(int(np.median(i))) in list` to do?

Comment: Please include your expected result. Your code has so many problems (undefined variables, function call as comprehension variable, function call that returns nothing, built-in name as variable), it's hard to tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, are looking for this

```
import numpy as np

list = [range(130, 135), range(135, 140), range(140, 145), range(145, 150), range(150, 155), range(155, 160), range(160, 165)]

x1 = [int(np.median(i)) for x1 in list for i in x1]
print(x1)
```